# How to use Xpath Wildcard in with dynamic class Name

Tags: php, xpath

I'm rather new to Xpath maybe someone can help.

My Expression looks like this:

```
.//*[@id='existingContractsTable:0:createNewDeviceUpgradeForm:createNewDeviceUpgradeSpan']
```

This works fine so far if there is only 1 Table.

The Problem is there are "sometimes" multiple Tables

which i could call with:

```
.//*[@id='existingContractsTable:1:createNewDeviceUpgradeForm:createNewDeviceUpgradeSpan']
.//*[@id='existingContractsTable:2:createNewDeviceUpgradeForm:createNewDeviceUpgradeSpan']
```

etc.

Is there any Wildcard i could use for that Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a wildcard in that way, but you do have several other creative options:

1. use `translate` to turn all numbers into spaces and then use `normalize-space` to deal with the cases for table 10 and onwards.
2. use `starts-with` `and` `ends-with`
3. use this combination: `substring-before` and `starts-with`:

   ```
   .//*[starts-with(substring-before(@id,':createNewDeviceUpgradeForm:createNewDeviceUpgradeSpan'), 'existingContractsTable:')]
   ```